# Automating GDB with IA32 and an fgets() call

Tags: python, c, x86, gdb, fgets

I am slogging through a tricky GDB debug of IA-32 code.  I've set up my .gdbinit file with all the commands I need to step through the early parts of the program.  Trouble is, at about halfway through, the code makes a call to fgets():

```
x0x8049260  call   0x80487d0 <fgets@plt>
```

This is problematic because GDB halts at this point and waits for the human user to enter a string.  I'd love it if the .gdbinit file could provide that string.  But I don't see anything in the GDB documentation that says how to do this.

Does anyone know if what I want to do is possible?  Or do I need an external Python script to run GDB for me?

Comment: Why don't you simply redirect a file to the process' `stdin`?

Comment: @EOF  Yeah, that's a good idea.  I'll read up on how to do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I stumbled on the .gdbinit file, which allows me to automate all commands proceeding the fgets() call and then all commands after.  So all I had to do was set those commands in the file, run gdb and my program, and manually enter the fgets() input.  It was a little cumbersome, but not terrible.